# Using multiple Auth in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, api, laravel, authentication, jwt

I'm creating a RESTApi in laravel 5.3 along with my API I also make a web application for admin use. In this web app I'm using laravel's easy auth (php artisan make:auth) which work just fine, but before starting up my web app I use JWT auth for my RESTApi. Now when I try to get a user from a JWToken with this call

```
 Auth:user()
```

It does not return the right user, it returns the user in my 'Admin' model. I have two model, User and Admin, where User is used for my API and Admin is for my web/admin app. Is there a way I can separate these two authentication so that I use easy auth for 'Admin' and JWT for 'User'?

In each my API controller I have this middleware in the constructor:

```
public function __construct()
{

    $this->middleware('jwt.auth');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try my package for multi auth in laravel 5.3. https://github.com/Hesto/multi-auth