# How to make two types of users in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to ask how to make two types of users in laravel. I have two tables, one for the customer and one for the client and my question is how to make that difference. Do I have to make two different models or to use model User and make some functions in middleware?

Thank you.

Comment: My question in the first place is why do you use two tables for the users? What is the difference between the users? Is not the generic information about the user the same? And would it not be better to have that in a separate table referring to the user. If you are thinking about using a user role system use instead an enum or an seperate table for this.

Comment: I have two different tables because of the informations about that users, client and customer have different informations and thats why I'm doing that

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for the simpliest solution, you can add `role` column to `users` table. Then you can check if user is a client or a customer **globally** with:

```
if (auth()->user()->role === 1) {
    // It's a client.
}
```

You can add some helper methods to check if user is a client or a customer:

```
public function isClient()
{
    return auth()->user() && auth()->user()->role === 1;
}
```

To open the part of the website for client only you should use route groups and middleware.

Comment: It's not about the roles of users, I have different informations about client and customer and thats why I can't put client and customer at the same table..

Comment: @epowah use the method I described and add two models which are in one-to-one relationship with `User` model. Store same data (email, password, name etc.) in `User` model and everything else in `ClientProfile` and `CustomerProfile`, for example. If your app has a lot of relationships and complicated queries, I'd recommend you to store all users related data in a single `users` table.

Comment: can you give me some more details or if you can some example I will be very glad

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same situation and I've resolved it by using a package that handles multi-authentication:
Check out this package:

- https://packagist.org/packages/hesto/multi-auth

There are also a blog post about this situation:

- http://santo.sh/multi-login-for-laravel-5-3/

and of course more StackOverflow questions:

- [Using multiple Auth in Laravel 5.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39782263/using-multiple-auth-in-laravel-5-3)
- [Multiple Authentication in Laravel 5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39543967/multiple-authentication-in-laravel-5-3)